# mupen64plus-ae: Edit keybindings for save/load state?

Tags: android, sdl, emulation

On my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3, I have Mupen64Plus-AE installed with a Super Mario 64 ROM.  I recently bought an adapter that allowed me to hook up anything with a USB connector to the charging port on the tablet.

Me, being me, decided to try to configure M64P-AE to work with my keyboard.  I adjusted the regular settings for the analog pad (A+B+L+R+Z+Start+Up+Down+Left+Right), but I was wondering if there was a way to edit the keybindings for other options such as saving state so I don't have to reach over and hit the button.

I have already tried editing lines 48 and 49 in mupen64plus.cfg in /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.free/, but when I launched the game, the changes didn't seem to be there. (I used the [SDL Keysym listing](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/include/SDL_keysym.h).)  Also, when I went back to the config file, the changes had been reset.

I can't find any option for these in the regular settings of the game.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I had to open up the control editor, then go to the sandwich menu and select 'Show special functions.'